# JOIN expression not supported, trying to LEFT JOIN and only return nulls

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010, ado

I'm trying to join two tables in Excel and only get the values in the first table that don't match values in the second table.  I'm using ADO, with the Access database engine.  SQL is:

```
SELECT a
    ,b
    ,c
FROM [data$a1:c3]
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT d
        ,e
        ,f
    FROM [data$e1:g3]
    ) ON a = e
WHERE e IS NULL
```

I'm getting a "JOIN expression not supported" error.  I can't see anything wrong with my SQL; what's the problem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this simpler form?

```
SELECT t1.a, t1.b, t1.c
FROM [data$a1:c3] as t1 LEFT JOIN
     [data$e1:g3] as t2
     ON t1.a = t2.e
WHERE t2.e IS NULL;
```

A derived table may require an alias, which is the cause of your syntax error.